# VBA Userform - Add value in same row based on another cell value

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm trying to find a way to add a value through userform based on a lot number of another cell.
Example: Trying to add value (time in hours format HH:MM) in column H (immersion time) according to column K (lot number) which is filledin the form. In short "I want to add 2 hours in LOT Number 2".
[Userform opened through the commandbutton1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUzaD.png)
[Excel being worked on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrk0i.png)

Please, help me with a solution. I'm quite new in this but getting attached really fast to it and I'm loving it.

```
Private Sub Apply_Click()

  Dim sh As Worksheet, lastrow As Long
  Dim rowlast As Integer
  Set sh = Sheets("SVPA")
  Set prep = Sheets("Preparo de solução")
  
  
        If SSOTEXT.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Favor, inserir SSO / Please, insert SSO"
      ElseIf SOETEXT.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox "Favor, inserir SOE / Please, insert SOE"
      ElseIf ATA.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox "Favor, inserir CÓDIGO ATA / Please, insert ATA CODE"
      ElseIf QTD.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox "Favor, inserir Quantidade de Peças / Please insert part quantity"
      ElseIf IMERTEXT.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox "Favor, inserir tempo de imersão / Please, insert Immersion Time"
           
        End If
        
  LastRow1 = prep.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value
  
  lastrow = sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
  
    sh.Range("A" & lastrow).Value = SSOTEXT.Value
    sh.Range("B" & lastrow).Value = "=VLOOKUP(A:A,SSO!$C$4:$D$12,2,FALSE)"
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    sh.Range("C" & lastrow).Value = SOETEXT.Text
    sh.Range("D" & lastrow).Value = ATA.Text
    sh.Range("N" & lastrow).Value = QTD.Text
    sh.Range("E" & lastrow).Value = Now
    sh.Range("F" & lastrow).Value = Range("E" & lastrow).Value + Range("H" & lastrow).Value
    sh.Range("G" & lastrow).Value = IMERTEXT.Text
    sh.Range("L" & lastrow).Value = TanqueTEXT.Text
    Range("M" & lastrow).Value = LastRow1
    
    
    
    
' NÚMERO DE LOTE
    rowlast = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(sh.Range("A:A"))
    If rowlast >= 1 Then
        Sheets("SVPA").Range("K" & lastrow).Value = rowlast - 1
        
        End If
    
    
    Unload Me
    
End Sub
```

The workbook already has another userform for information inputs and that second button is optional (as well the third and fourth button will be).

Comment: Welcome to SO. What problems are you getting? Any errors? Which line? did you debug with F8?

Comment: Hello, thank you for warm welcome. I'm trying to create a code to fill the SECOND IMMERSION TIME based on which LOT NUMBER I fill in the userform, which will be on the same row

Comment: If each `Lot Number` is unique, you can use [MATCH](https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-application-match/) to locate row number and then use that row number in column `Inmersion time` and write the value you wish.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I se MATCH can help me with another issue but for this one specifically I was able to make it work through the code below

Private Sub ADD_Click()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim MatchingRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim SearchedValue As String
Set sh = Worksheets("SVPA")

SearchedValue = LOTNUMBER.Value

For i = 1 To 10000
     If StrComp(sh.Range("K" & i).Value, SearchedValue, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
          MatchingRow = i
          Exit For
     End If
Next i

sh.Range("H" & MatchingRow).Value = ADDIMMER.Value

Unload Me


End Sub